# File sharing with a specific user in database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have created a login in SQL Server. The login has only read-only permissions. Database role membership for this user are `db_backupoperator`, `db_datareader`, `db_denydatawriter` and `public`. I gave him permissions to make backups, but when I try to access folder directory of the system it shows an error like in the picture below.

How can I share a specific folder to this Login in order to save backups to this folder?

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Backups are generally made by the user that the SQL Server process runs under, and are secured from other users. (After all, a SQL Login will have no access to the machine.) Check the folder again as administrator.

Comment: The situation is that I have to create database Login where he can only make backups , meanwhile he do not have administrator Login credencials.

Comment: Let's step back a bit. When does that error come up? Are you trying to look at the backup via Explorer? Are you using SQL Server Express?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in and I want to make a backup of my database. When I open the File Explorer to choose the location of the backup, it shows me the error above. I need to give permissions somehow to this user to open the File Explorer but I dont know how. Thanks for response

Comment: You need to give him read-only access to that folder. That's his windows logon, not the sql logon.

Comment: But how can give permissions to this Login in order to save backups to that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The user logs in to the SQL Server instance via a SQL Server logon, and asks for a backup to be made.
2. The SQL Server process, running under whatever Windows Identity it
   is (LOCAL SYSTEM on my dev machine) makes the backup.
3. The user who asked for the backup in step 1 uses Windows Explorer to
   check the backup folder. Note that Windows Explorer is using his
   Windows Identity (NOT his SQL Logon) to check whether or not he has
   access to that folder
4. Windows Explorer decides that this Windows user does not have access and
   displays the message you show above.

To change the outcome, you need to give the Windows Logon that the user is using access to the backup folder. To do this, log on as an Admin, right click on the folder in explorer and select the Security tab. Add the Windows Logon that the backup person uses and give read access to the folder.

Just to clear, the backups are likely being done properly (absent any other data), but his WINDOWS logon is not allowed to see them.